# Can Printer Extension UI use the Universal Windows Platform (UWP)?

Tags: c#, .net, driver, windows-10, wdk

Can `Printer Extension` UI use the Universal Windows Platform (`UWP`)?

Comment: Why would you think it couldnt?

Comment: This can be done in WPF application, I tried with UWP not able to do it, because the "printerextensionlibrary" class library provided by Microsoft is not compatible with UWP .

Comment: What assembly/namespace "printerextensionlibrary" refers to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PrinterExtensionLibrary is part of the "Windows Store device apps" stack, not .Net Core (UWP).
Found [this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing), that shows you how to print in an UWP-App.

Comment: You are right, but I think this is not what I'm looking for. I want to make the whole v4 printer driver UI (PrinterExtension) in UWP.

Comment: Yeah, but that was a "No" to your question and therefore the right answer. Would have liked that bounty. :(

Comment: Answer to my question is "No". Take the 50 bounty.